# Report Builder 3.0: What is the correct value for the average of this field?

Tags: reporting-services, sum, average

Not sure if this belongs in Mathematics SE so just let me know and I can move it.

I am building a report in Report Builder 3.0 and I need to show how much we used on average over the course of a month.

Which value makes more sense here? Taking the average of the averages (5.3%, shown in image) or taking those sums at the bottom of the table and finding the overage that way? In the 2nd case, the calculation would be variance divided by qty required x 100%, or  `274,213.02/6,283,281.11 * 100% = 4.4%`. The last 4 columns in the image are `quantity required`, `quantity used`, `(quantity used - quantity required)` or `variance`, and `(quantity used - quantity required)/quantity required` or `overage`.

[Screenshot of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9hpT.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to get the overall average is "across" at the bottom - take the average of the sums.

If you average the averages, you give every subgroup equal weighting which is incorrect (usually). If you have two divisions, one of which made an average 5% profit on $100K sales and another which made an average 1% profit on $100M sales, the smaller division will unfairly "pull up" the whole company.

Or, to use a sports analogy: when calculating a hitter's batting average, you don't take their previous BA, then average it with the latest game's performance. You total up **all** of their at-bats and hits, and average *that*.